# history pushstate fetch the url parameter using PHP

Tags: php, jquery

im trying to fetch the url parameter i pass to my current url, and i already use PHP get, post, request function to fetch, but nothing happened?

look at my code:

```
           PHP:

           echo $_POST['x'];// current page
           echo $_REQUEST['x'];// current page
           echo $_GET['x'];// current page

          jquery:
          history.pushState({}, '', 'daone.php?x=1'); // current page
```

Comment: what you getting result after echo 1? and show what url shows on the page

Comment: `history.pushState` is not refreshing page. You have to send request (which is/or refreshing the page) to server.

Comment: show url: daone.php?x=1 and no echo made instead Notice: Undefined index: x in D:\xampp\htdocs\testing\daone.php on line 2

Comment: why not use `window.location.href = "daone.php?x=1";`

Comment: @Ghost, I use some modal on it, after historypushstate next line will be the .modal('show'). if i use window.location.href it reload the page and also the modal.

Comment: then use `$.ajax` instead

Comment: @Ghost, $.ajax keeps me slowing the load of my form, because my form inputed are so compose of 50 inputbox. very slow when fetching data from $.ajax, any other way i could lighten my code?